Minimum time required by a curve to reenter a closed ball with radius equal to the reciprocal of its maximum curvature
I have a continuously differentiable curve $r : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n \ge 2$, with the properties
\begin{align}
\lvert r'(t) \rvert = 1 \text{ for all } t \in \mathbb{R}, \\
\lvert r'(t) - r'(s) \rvert \le \kappa \lvert t - s \rvert \text{ for all } t,s \in \mathbb{R},\\ \lvert r(0) \rvert  = 1 / \kappa, \\
\langle r(0), r'(0) \rangle > 0,
\end{align}
where $\kappa > 0$.
For all curves with the above properties, I'm looking for a lower bound $t_{0} > 0$ such that $t > 0$ and $\lvert r(t) \rvert = 1 / \kappa$ implies $t > t_{0}$.
Intuitively, the curve that achieves $\lvert r(t) \rvert = 1/\kappa$ in minimum time for given $r(0)$ and $r'(0)$ is a circular arc with radius $1/\kappa$ contained in the plane spanned by $r(0)$ and $r'(0)$ (or any plane containing $r(0)$ if they are parallel). Over all such circular arcs, I believe we would then have $t_{0} = \pi / \kappa$.
I would be grateful for any reference I could cite for such a lower bound on $t$.

Yes, the answer is $\pi/\kappa$.
You can get it as a corollary of the bow lemma (following the same argument as in the hints to 3.25 here)
Connect the origin to $r(0)$ by a smooth convex plane curve $\gamma$ so that the product $\gamma*r$ is piecewise smooth and $C^1$-smooth.
By the bow lemma, you get that $|r(t)|\ge |\tilde r(t)|$, where $\tilde r$ is a plane curve with constant curvature $\kappa$ that bends toward the origin and such that $|r(0)|=|\tilde r(0)|$ and $|r(0)|'=|\tilde r(0)|'$.
It remains to check that $|\tilde r(\pi/\kappa)|>\tfrac1\kappa$.
Alternatively, you can apply Reshetnayk's majorization theorem, but you will see more technical problems on the way.
